# How to read a little at a time from UnixStream connected to socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, rust

I am trying to read some data of unknown size from a `UnixStream` (called `socket` in this code). The data consists of a header of 6 bytes, and the last two bytes indicate how long the rest of the message should be.

The [`.into_buf()`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.4.12/bytes/trait.IntoBuf.html#tymethod.into_buf) method I'm calling is from the `IntoBuf` trait in Tokio's `bytes` crate.

```rust
let mut header = [0u8; 6];
let response1 = self.socket.read(&mut header);
let mut cursor = header.into_buf();

let evt_code = cursor.get_u16_le();
let controller = cursor.get_u16_le();
let param_size = cursor.get_u16_le() as usize;

let mut param = vec![0u8; param_size];
let response2 = self.socket.read(&mut param);
let mut cursor = param.into_buf();
```

The problem that I'm encountering is that `response2` is always an `Err` E_WOULDBLOCK because my `UnixStream` is connected to a nonblocking socket. It seems that the first call to `read()` is reading 6 bytes as intended, but then is just discarding the rest of the content in the stream.

How can I work around this / how can I make `read()` leave the extra data in the stream?

It seems like the simplest solution would be to just make my initial buffer big and then just read everything at once, but the problem with this is that the largest possible message I could receive is a little over 64KB. Allocating or re-zeroing a 64KB buffer for every read seems quite wasteful, especially because most of the messages are much smaller than this.

Comment: This socket is not connected to the network or to a file, I am using it to interact with a kernel API. Therefore, I don't know if using `BufReader` makes any sense here (and I'm not sure how I would be able to read _and_ write if I use `BufReader`)

Comment: Why are you using non-blocking mode if that's not what you want?

Comment: @user207421 Perhaps I misunderstood what exactly non-blocking mode does ... I thought that if I use blocking mode, then when I try to read the socket when there is no input, then the program will stall (which is not desired behaviour)

Comment: @user207421 Changing the socket to blocking mode didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this by using a raw file descriptor instead of a `UnixStream` and calling `recv()` with `MSG_PEEK`.

```rust
let mut header = [0u8; 6];

// need MSG_PEEK otherwise recv() clears the socket and we get EAGAIN when
// we try to read the socket again; this is the main reason for using a raw
// fd instead of a UnixStream
if unsafe { libc::recv(self.fd, header.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void, 6, libc::MSG_PEEK) } < 0 {
    return Err(io::Error::last_os_error().into());
}

let mut cursor = header.into_buf();

let evt_code = cursor.get_u16_le();
let controller = cursor.get_u16_le();
let param_size = cursor.get_u16_le() as usize;


// since calling recv() with MSG_PEEK doesn't consume the header, we need to make
// this buffer 6 bytes bigger, but that's fine
let mut param = vec![0u8; param_size + 6];

if unsafe { libc::recv(self.fd, param.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void, param.len(), 0) } < 0 {
    return Err(io::Error::last_os_error().into());
}

let mut cursor = param.into_buf();
```